# How to disable automatic .NET Core package restore?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, nuget-package-restore

By default, if you edit dependencies in project.json, Visual Studio starts package restore automatically. Is it possible to disable this behavior?

I am playing with `dotnet restore` arguments, and for testing purposes I'm editing `project.json`/removing `project.lock.json`. But VS automatically runs default "dotnet restore" after any changes, which is interrupting my testing.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the actual problem you are experiencing?

Comment: And why do you hate IntelliSense?

Comment: have updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to turn off transient package restore in the Package Manager Settings section of the Visual Studio options window:

[image: Uncheck "Allow Nuget to download missing packages"]

Unchecking **Allow Nuget to download missing packages** will stop Visual Studio from restoring packages when you edit project.json.